# Git add only all new files, not modified files

Tags: git, git-add

Is there a way to only add new files and not add modified files with git? That is, files that are listed as untracked with git status.

Other than ofcourse adding each file separately.

It's not absolutely necessary to do this in my case, the real question for me is answered here: [How to make git-diff and git log ignore new and deleted files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894322/how-to-make-git-diff-and-git-log-ignore-new-and-deleted-files)

That is, don't show diff on new files, so I'm asking this more because i couldn't find an answer to it anywhere.

Comment: What is the use case for that? Because I don't see how it would make sense to add files and not add relevant changes in existing files and if the changes are not relevant than the changes to be committed likely need to be hand-picked on some other criteria.

Comment: My workflow is i check each file with diff and then i add it to "get it out of the way" kind of. So that git diff now only shows the files that are left for me to check. So i want to add new files (assuming or believing them to be "ok") to get them out of the way.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe

```
git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)
```

`git ls-files` lets you list the files managed by git, filtered by some options. `-o` in this case filters it to only show "others (i.e. untracked files)"

The `$(...)` statement passes the return value of that command as an argument to `git add`.

Comment: You'll need to exclude the ignored files again, otherwise `git add` will complain. E.g. by using the `--exclude-standard` flag to the `git ls-files -o` call.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it *only* complains, telling you that it will ignore those files and that if you want to really add them, you'll have to use the `--force` flag. Still, annoying.

Comment: Works but it will add untracked files.

Comment: Works in `PowerShell` on Windows OS

Answer (score 8):

You can use short mode of git status (see [man git-status(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html)), which gives the following output:

Without short mode:

```
$ git status

...


# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   README
#   application/libraries/Membres_exception.php
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

With short mode:

```
$ git status -s
 M application/models/membre_model.php
?? README
?? application/libraries/Membres_exception.php
```

Then using grep, awk and xarg, you can add the files where the first column is `??`.

```
$ git status -s | grep '??' | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs git add
```

and see that it worked:

```
$ git status
# On branch new
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   README
#   new file:   application/libraries/Membres_exception.php
```

Comment: good idea, though there's a problem: in case where filepath contains spaces `awk '{ print $2 }'` will grab only first part of such filepath.

Comment: how about this one: `git status -s | grep '??' | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $2))}' | xargs git add`