# Preserving only file additions from a series of Git commits?

Tags: git, version-control

Let `A<-B<-C` be a sequence of Git commits.

Commits `B` and `C` introduce 3 types of changes:

1. Adding some files.
2. Modifying some files.
3. Deleting some files.

Unfortunately, the changes of type 2 and 3 in both `B` and `C` turned out to be incorrect. Therefore we need to derive a modified sequence `A<-B'<-C'`, where `B'` and `C'` only include the file additions from the original `A` and `B`, discarding any Modifications or Deletions.

How can that be done?

If it helps, we don't absolutely need `B'` and `C'` as separate commits; we can do with just `A<-D`, where `D` contains every file added in either `B` or `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try resetting to A, and add all new files:

```
# reset index, reset HEAD to A, preserve working tree.
git reset A

# Add only new files
git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)

# Make commit D (equals B and C new files)
git commit -m "only new files from B and C"
```

For the second step (adding only new files), see "[Git add only all new files, not modified files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15761890/6309)".

---

The [OP Dun Peal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916907/dun-peal) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819041/preserving-only-file-additions-from-a-series-of-git-commits/20819405#comment31219351_20819405):

> C removes some of the files introduced by B. Thus the C working copy does not include all the files introduced by B. I guess I could jut iterate over the commits one at a time, and perform this for each one.

Yes, an iterative approach is needed:

```
git reset --hard B
git reset A
git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)
git commit -m "only new files from B"
```

That produces commit `B'`.

Repeat for `C`, using `B'` as a base:

```
git reset --hard C
git reset B'
git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)
git commit -m "only new files from C"
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's a slight complication: `C` removes some of the files introduced by `B`. Thus the `C` working copy does not include all the files introduced by `B`. I guess I could jut iterate over the commits one at a time, and perform this for each one.

Comment: @DunPeal I agree. I have edited the answer to give an idea of what said iterative approach would look like.